# How to print my sql output from console.log into html with rows and column

Tags: html, node.js, npm

Below is my sample code in HTML I have to print the data with proper table format

```
redshiftClient.query('SELECT top 10 * FROM table')
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var mail = {
            from: '******@outlook.com',
            to: '******@test.co.in',
            subject: "Send Email Using Node.js",
            text: "Node.js New world for me",
            html: ""
        }
```

Expected Output in email

```
id  name  age  gender
1   abc    10   M
2   def    20   M
```

Comment: Can you show me the data that comes in 'data'(console.log(data))

Comment: rows:
   [ anonymous { id: 3, name: 'c', salary: 50 },
     anonymous { id: 1, name: 'k', salary: 100 },
     anonymous { id: 6, name: 'e', salary: 90 },
     anonymous { id: 4, name: 'd', salary: 90 },
     anonymous { id: 2, name: 'b', salary: 10 },
     anonymous { id: 5, name: 'e', salary: 1000 } ]

Comment: Have you considered using a view engine? It would make it much easier i believe. https://colorlib.com/wp/top-templating-engines-for-javascript/

Comment: Create a html table from your data, then put the table to your email content.

Answer (score 0):

you can have variety of npm packages, example [console.table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/console.table). Check this

```
const cTable = require('console.table');
const table = cTable.getTable([
  {
    name: 'foo',
    age: 10
  }, {
    name: 'bar',
    age: 20
  }
]);

console.log(table);
```

Comment: you have to  install console.table package  npm install console.table --save

Comment: for few data ok if I have more than 20 data

Comment: in that case, it's better to create csv / excel from json and that can attached with the mail

Answer (score 0):

You need a packge which can convert an array of objects to html. something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-json2html can do the trick. Basically pass the data to transform function and it will give you proper html which can be sent via sending email. The email will be rendered as proper table. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am using something like this but I am getting only last record.

```
for (let index = 0; index < data.rows.length; index++) {
            const element = data.rows[index];
            //console.log(element)
            //console.log(element.id);

            var mail = {
                from: 'xxx@outlook.com',
                to: 'xxxxs@gmail.co.in',
                subject: `Daily AWS validation check for the ${new Date().getTime()}`,
                html: `<h1> Hello Team, Here is the hourly data pull</h1> <br> <table><tr> <th>Hoursdata</th> <th>Book_Counts</th> <th>Search_Counts</th> <th>Hit_Counts</th> <tr><td>${element.run_hour}</td> <td>${element.book_counts}</td> <td>${element.search_counts}</td> <td>${element.hit_counts}</td></tr> </table>`
            }
        }
```